# Why my app clip's size is more than 10 MB

Tags: ios, static-libraries, apple-appclips

So, I already have a project with multiple pods installed. Here is the size of the main app's IPA as per app thinning report with Bitcode enabled:

> App + On Demand Resources size: 30.7 MB compressed, 52 MB uncompressed

If I unzip the IPA file and take a look at its executable file, **it's 22.5 MB.**
So, I just create a new target in xcworkspace for App Clip. I neither add its target to Podfile nor add any code to the App Clip project. Then, I archive the app and export the app clip to check its size. Here is the outcome:

> App + On Demand Resources size: 8.1 MB compressed, 22 MB uncompressed

If I check its executable, **the size is 21.9 MB**.
How can I inspect what's adding to its size? or any suggestions on how can I trim down its executable file?

**A few things to note**:

- there are no bundle assets(images/videos)
- there are no libraries linked in Build Phases
- I also used this command on my executable **otool -L**  to check for static libraries and the following was the outcome:
  [Terminal output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2IXY5.png)

Comment: Try to minimize the cocoapod use in your App Clip experience... some pods are very bloated... but I'm not sure how to test how much each pod adds to the app size :/

Comment: Having a similar issue, only have ContentView.swift added to my App Clip and it is being rejected as being too big. Did you find a solution to this ?